# How to LOCK/BLOCK selected row in table to be ReadOnly?

Tags: mariadb, table

Is it possible to LOCK completely or make READ-ONLY where id = value in MariaDB?
or add some trigger locking if someone is trying to update selected row ?

Some people says:
"Trigger is not a good way to prevent update" .... well, just because MySQL/MariaDB allow you to do it and it is the easiest solution I decided to use/create one as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
    FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.locked THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You are not allowed to change 
    this record, please contact your_administrator';
    END IF
```

As long as it does the job .... i'm happy.
If there is any "against" please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When would you unlock it?

A typical pattern is:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
scratch your head, then eventually
UPDATE that row (or not)
COMMIT;
```

That keeps anyone else from messing with the row, but they can read it.  It's not quite "ReadOnly", and the "lock" is released at the `COMMIT`.

If this does not suffice, please describe your use case more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you Rick, sorted it already. Yes, the recoed can be read just cannot be updated at any time once is set. So I created a trigger locking record while UPDATE.

Comment: @RobD.A. - Since what you did is different than my Answer and it is closer to what the Question asks, I suggest you add an Answer (not just a Comment) that shows details of the Trigger, explains why it does what the Question requests, etc.  Then take the Accepted flag away from my Answer.